# Assigning instance variance in method leads to segfault

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault

Below is rather basic objective-c code.  It contains one instance variable `i`.  The problem is whenever I attempt to assign to it, it leads to segfault almost immediately following that assignment operation.  Note:  It does not segfault at the point of assignment.  Usually it segfaults after the assignment and I try to invoke a method.  ALSO, notice that this is not your standard mac/apple objective-c code.  I'm using cygwin (Linux) plain vanilla version of objective-c.  So I have to generate my own `alloc` and `dealloc` methods.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>

@interface Test
{
    int i;
}

+(id)alloc;
- (id) init;
- (int) load;
@end

@implementation Test

+(id)alloc
{
    self = class_createInstance(self,0);
    return self;
}

-(id)init
{
    i = 0; // <------ if I comment out this line, there is no segfault
    return self;
}

-(int) load
{
    return i;
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test * test = [[Test alloc] init];
    int v = [test load]; //segfaults here (NOTE: if I comment out this line, it does not segfault)
    return 0;
}
```

What is causing the segfault?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like if (self = [super init]) { i = 0; } ?

Comment: It's a little weird that `+alloc` assigns to and then returns `self`. That is initially the class object (roughly, `Class self`), so assigning an instance to it is "wrong". Don't know if that matters, though.

Comment: @onnoweb This is a root class. There is no superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that, for a root class like yours, you need to explicitly declare the `isa` instance variable. Without it, your `i` is being interpreted as though it were the `isa`, which is why you get a crash.

So:

```
@interface Test
{
    Class isa;
    int i;
}
```

If you didn't intend to create a root class, you should probably inherit from `Object` or the like.

Comment: Excellent !!  I just added the `isa` instance variable and I'm not getting the segfault error anymore (up vote).  I'm a C/C++ programmer and almost gave up on Objective-C because of this.  Glad I don't have to.  Will do some more testing and if it passes I'll mark as the answer.